# I am trying to extract from text file data and add it into the audioread function Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am extracting some data "names" from a txt file and I am trying to use that name for the audioread() function in order to go into the Matlab location and open the corresponding audio signal WAV or mp3.

```
 fid = fopen('names.txt','rt');
           text= fscanf(fid,'%s',1);
           index = 0;
           text = fscanf(fid,'%s',1);
           while(strcmp(text,'.')~=1)            
            index = index+1;            
            storeD{index} = text;
            signal=strcat('''',storeD,'.wav''');% or mp3
            x=audioread(signal);
            text = fscanf(fid,'%s',1);
            end
           fclose(fid);
```

The problem now is that I am getting an error :
Expected input to be a non-missing string scalar or character vector. for this line here x=audioread(signal);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer storing multiple audio signals in a structure since they can be variable length and don't fit nicely into one variable of the array. Also just adjusted some of the name parsings. I also assumed the text file would be configured as so:

### names.txt:

```
Jacob
Shawn
Sydney
Maria
Joseph
.
```

**If the files are in a subfolder names Music:**

```
./Music/Jacob
./Music/Shawn
./Music/Sydney
./Music/Maria
./Music/Joseph
.
```

[image: Reading Data Flow Chart]

Depending on how the strings are formatted in the file this line may have to be edited:

```
signal = strcat(storeD,'.wav');% or mp3
```

### MATLAB Script:

```
Signal_Number = 1;
Audio_Signals = struct('Audio_File',[]);

fid = fopen('names.txt','rt');

%Grabbing the first name to start%
index = 1;
text = fscanf(fid,'%s',1);

%Continue to loop%
while(strcmp(text,'.')~=1)   
    
storeD{index} = text;
index = index+1;            
signal = strcat(storeD,'.wav');% or mp3


Audio_Signals(Signal_Number).Audio_File = audioread(signal{1,Signal_Number});
Signal_Number = Signal_Number + 1;
text = fscanf(fid,'%s',1);
end
fclose(fid);

Fs = 44100;
Audio_1 = Audio_Signals(1).Audio_File;
Audio_2 = Audio_Signals(2).Audio_File;
Audio_3 = Audio_Signals(3).Audio_File;

%Playing audio 1%
sound(Audio_3,Fs);

storeD
```

### Extension: Reading LAB and CSV Files Based on Text File Names

### Contents of .LAB File

```
Alex\A23
John\B21
Nick\K36
```

**Using MATLAB version: R2019b**

Comment: Thanks very much for your help and explanation the only problem now is that the Audio_1 corresponds to audio 2 in the file. For example, John wav is first, and second is Alex and it plays Alex first and it seems it jumps some files as well.

Comment: @Grey_Hunter oh, I thought that was purposeful to skip the first lines. I was trying to carry over what you had in the original. I’ll edit it.

Comment: I cannot see my mistake, can you please explain?

Comment: I updated my answer. Sorry, it was late from where I'm from.

Comment: I have another question in order to implement the same logic in CSV and LAB file what I need to change in the  Audio_Signals(Signal_Number).Audio_File = audioread(signal{1,Signal_Number}); in order to be compatible?

Comment: @Grey_Hunter Do you mean if the input is a CSV or LAB file instead of the TEXT file?

Comment: sorry I did not explain it very well. The code we were working on reads from TxT files and then goes and read wav signals. Now I would like to same but instead of wav I would like to read CSV and Lab files.

Comment: Do you have an example of what the CSV file contents be like? You'd most likely would have to use a form of csvread() instead of audioread().

Comment: Please see the example with the lab file it has one column with names and numbers 
  Alex\A23 
John\B21
Nick\K36
and so on

Comment: Please see the updated image in my answer. Which colour block are you trying to replace with CSV and LAB files in the chain?

Comment: I am trying to replace the wav directory with lab and CSV files. They should not be together with the CSV and Lab files( one option will be to read from lab and the second option will be read from CSV), I have now started with the lab files. I am trying to do exactly the same as your block diagram first read the txt file and then go and read the corresponding lab file. The TXT file reads line by line as in every single line I would need to go and read the appropriate lab file.

Comment: Any chance you could post the LAB file?

Comment: I hope the below link works. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmFhoFjq6d9rhz-34jZ_njPUV90-?e=DuREAO

it has more similar lab files with the building but the same format.

Comment: Couldn't find .LAB files as a supported file for import and export. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/supported-file-formats.html